# df.to_csv writes everything in the same column of cells

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to export the following dataframe to a csv file

[image]

with the following line of code:

```
df.to_csv("Result.csv", encoding = "utf-8-sig")
```

but the output looks really weird:

[image]

I would like it to use the different columns of the csv to input the data, but what it's doing is putting everything in the same column of cells.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSV looks good to me. Excel uses e.g. semicolon in some locales so it doesn't import CSV files in that locale. You could use `to_csv(..., sep=';')` and see if it helps. In the end, it will depend on the locale settings on the computer in which the CSV is opened, so you can never be sure that your code will work "correctly" with Excel.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So in the end there is no way to use instead of "," the different cells in the CSV?
For example, in the first row, have CLUSTER0 be in column A, cluster1 be in column B etc.

Comment: As I was saying, use `sep=';'` and see if that works for you. Again, it's an Excel setting, which symbol it prefers. Aslo, you can use 'to_excel' instead if you are creating the file for Excel, rather than `to_csv`.